# Remove product image from checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, product-images, image

How to remove product picture from checkout page in `opc-block-summary` block
[image]

Comment: You want to using css???

Comment: @MohitPatel No, I would like hidden ones not to depend on CSS. so that the server does not make unnecessary requests.

Comment: Search the .phtml file path using template path hints and remove/comment the code showing the image.

Comment: @Alice - check below answer. It works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom module directory, create the new file `checkout_index_index.xml` at below location:

```
<your_module_dir>/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

In this file, add the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="details" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="thumbnail" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Result :

[image]

**NOTE:** If you have a custom theme, you can add the file `checkout_index_index.xml` at below location:

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor Theme}/{Theme}/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```